# How to fix a iOS crash " Crashed: WebThread EXC_BREAKPOINT"

Tags: ios, web, crash

Recently, I get many crash report in Fabric. But I never reproduce it when debug on Xcode. I have a webview, and it doesn't dealloc because another viewcontroller retain it and automatic reload with NSTimer. I also use runtime method to fire nstimer.

```
0   WebCore bmalloc::IsoAllocator<bmalloc::IsoConfig<72u> >::allocateSlow(bool) + 252
1   WebCore 
bmalloc::IsoAllocator<bmalloc::IsoConfig<72u> >::allocateSlow(bool) + 72
2   WebCore WebCore::Text::create(WebCore::Document&, WTF::String const&) + 152
3   WebCore WebCore::HTMLConstructionSite::insertTextNode(WTF::String const&, WebCore::WhitespaceMode) + 912
4   WebCore WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::processCharacterBufferForInBody(WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::ExternalCharacterTokenBuffer&) + 404
5   WebCore 
WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::processCharacterBuffer(WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::ExternalCharacterTokenBuffer&) + 2020
6   WebCore WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::processToken(WebCore::AtomicHTMLToken&&) + 204
7   WebCore WebCore::HTMLTreeBuilder::constructTree(WebCore::AtomicHTMLToken&&) + 92
8   WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::constructTreeFromHTMLToken(WebCore::HTMLTokenizer::TokenPtr&) + 156
9   WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizerLoop(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode, bool, WebCore::PumpSession&) + 380
10  WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizer(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode) + 116
11  WebCore WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::append(WTF::RefPtr<WTF::StringImpl, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WTF::StringImpl> >&&) + 920
12  WebCore WebCore::DecodedDataDocumentParser::appendBytes(WebCore::DocumentWriter&, char const*, unsigned long) + 116
13  WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitData(char const*, unsigned long) + 2660
14  WebKitLegacy    -[WebHTMLRepresentation receivedData:withDataSource:] + 112
15  WebKitLegacy    -[WebDataSource(WebInternal) _receivedData:] + 68
16  WebKitLegacy    WebFrameLoaderClient::committedLoad(WebCore::DocumentLoader*, char const*, int) + 112
17  WebCore WebCore::DocumentLoader::commitLoad(char const*, int) + 172
18  WebCore WebCore::CachedRawResource::notifyClientsDataWasReceived(char const*, unsigned int) + 344
19  WebCore WebCore::CachedRawResource::updateBuffer(WebCore::SharedBuffer&) + 212
20  WebCore WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveDataOrBuffer(char const*, int, WTF::RefPtr<WebCore::SharedBuffer, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebCore::SharedBuffer> >&&, long long, WebCore::DataPayloadType) + 396
21  WebCore WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didReceiveBuffer(WTF::Ref<WebCore::SharedBuffer, WTF::DumbPtrTraits<WebCore::SharedBuffer> >&&, long long, WebCore::DataPayloadType) + 100
22  WebCore WTF::Function<void ()>::CallableWrapper<-[WebCoreResourceHandleAsOperationQueueDelegate connection:didReceiveData:lengthReceived:]::$_6>::call() + 124
23  JavaScriptCore  WTF::dispatchFunctionsFromMainThread() + 288
24  Foundation  __NSThreadPerformPerform + 336
25  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
26  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
27  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
28  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1004
29  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
30  WebCore RunWebThread(void*) + 600
31  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body + 128
32  libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start + 44
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start + 4
```

Does anyone have the same problem?